# Download attribute for <a> does not work for pdfs and images

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to force the browser to download when it comes to a PDF or an image rather than opening a new tab. I use Google Chrome. However, when I test out the example under the following link, it works: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

But it does not work on mine (see following). Downloads still trigger for other file types but PDFs and images.
`const urls = res.data

```
  for (const idx in urls) {
    // check if each url is working, if it is working, stop and download it
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = urls[idx]
    link.target = '_blank'
    link.download = tgt.name
    link.rel = 'noopener noreferrer'
    document.body.appendChild(link)
    link.click()
    document.body.removeChild(link)
  }`
```

So, what have I done wrong here?

Comment: `urls[idx]`  is a URL... that URL is different from your current origin/hostname?

Answer (score 5):

Probably the problem is that the href URL is not the same as your origin, note that the `download` only works for:

1. same-origin URLs
2. BLOB file
3. data schema

well... now the solution is that to fetch the file first, then convert it to BLOB file, like the below example:

```
fetch("FILE URL!")
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
        /*
        here you have access to your BLOB file and
        only you have to put it in the href attribute
        */
    });
```

**NOTE:** *if the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header response has equal to `*`, we can get the response from any origin from that URL/origin, but we can't use the download attribute with that because the `href` URL is different from the current origin, In this case, behaviors are different.*

e.g:

```
"https://blahblah.com" Response Header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *
```

the current url/origin is = http://test.test.org

```
fetch("https://blahblah.com") //pass

<a download href="https://blahblah.com/file.pdf" /> //failed! (actually the download attribute does not work here)
```