# Download images with one click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why can't the images be downloaded with one click? What mistake did I make in my password? What could be wrong?
Here is my code:

```css
body {
  max-width: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: darkslategray;
}

.top-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: black;
}

.arrow-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.AvatarsHolder {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.Avatar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-div">
  <h1 style="color:white; font-family:Tahoma; text-align:left; padding-left:20px;">
    <a href="USER_PROFILE_AFTER_LOGIN.html" style="text-decoration: none; color:white;">AVATAR'S GALLERY</a></h1>
  <h1 style="text-align:center; font-family:Tahoma; color:white; padding-left:30px;"><br>Left click on the avatars you want to download them</h1>
  <div class="AvatarsHolder" style="background-color:white;"><br>
    <h2>Human's Avatars</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>
      <a href="Avatar0.png" download>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" title="Bold" class="Avatar">
      </a>
      <a href="Avatar1.png" download>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" title="Keyhole" class="Avatar">
      </a>
      <a href="Avatar2.png" download>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" title="Hipster" class="Avatar">
      </a>
      <a href="Avatar3.png" download>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" title="Rapper" class="Avatar">
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the images download with one click, I want when the user left clicks on an image it will automatically download to their computer.

Comment: Is the path of the image correctly? If the images are in the same level that the HTML try `<a href="./Avatar1.png" download></a>`

Comment: How are you testing this? There are some particular restrictions on downloading files depending on CORS. You need to have the downloadables on the same origin, and it _needs_ to be a valid origin (so not `file://`). I tested code similar to yours in `file://` and on a local server, and it worked on the latter but not the former. Here is an interesting post related to this (though not quite what you encounter) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575118/download-attribute-for-a-does-not-work-for-pdfs-and-images

Comment: With the changes you made to your example, it will _not_ work as the origin of the images is _different_ from Stack Overflow (and probably your site as well) _and_ all the images lack a CORS header as far as I can see, so instead of downloading it will follow the link, allowing a download there.

Comment: You probably need a little backend for this, the html download link could be outdated. I suggest javascript.

Comment: It all depends on the environment, which we don't know about. Are you running a local server? Are your images located on that server? Are you running this from the `file://` protocol? Etc...

Answer (score -1):

Assign the image src attribute value to the anchor tag's href attribute and it's better if the url points to a file, i.e., it ends with .jpg or .png or.webp

Refer this:
[href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Comment: Why would it better if the URL points to a file ending with `.jpg`, `.png`, etc.? Furthermore OP's original snippet *did* contain URL's ending in an extension, but was edited to create a minimal example

Comment: File ending with .jpg or.png is better because it's directly recognised as an image file. It's optional if the image server is setting the content type as image/jpg or image/png.

Comment: @DarkBee , we do not have access to the original snippet that you are speaking of. Where can I find it?

Comment: Not really, the fact that a `jpg` is displayed immediately is because your browser is configured as such

Comment: You can click the link "Editted by"/"Eddited X hours ago" to see the revisions of a post - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76819712/revisions)

Comment: @DarkBee , thanks. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need the images to be on the server you are using to be able to download.

Example the following Code will work on W3school editor but will not work in your Code:

Link to Try: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

Code:

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
 <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" title="Bold"         class="Avatar">
</a>
```

Comment: "*need the images to be on the server you are using to be able to download*" - Could you add a reference to support your claim? Also OP's images are on his/her own server as seen in the original snippet